# how do you force public wifi connect modal to open on MacOS?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

Most public wifi's at coffee shops have a little modal that opens after you connect. It's just a browser window but it has a little checkbox and click here to connect button. Sometimes I'll connect to those wifi's and the modal will not popup. Is there anyway to force it to? I try turning the wifi on and off and reconnecting, and the wifi is connected just fine and I have an IP, but nothing works until I get that model and check the box. If I reboot the whole machine I'll get the modal. Any way to get it without having to reboot?

when I goto a url in chrome i get:
[image]
when I goto a url in safari i get:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, go to an insecure website if you want to deal with the captive portal page again. Captive portals can't MITM HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about that window. When joining a new network, the system detects if insecure HTTP requests are being redirected to a "captive portal" web page (as it is called in the public Wi-Fi industry), and pops up that window to let you deal with it. No settings change on your Mac. If you deal with the captive portal successfully, the network you're on is what stops getting in your way.

So, if that modal window doesn't pop up again, it suggests the network is not redirecting insecure HTTP requests to a captive portal anymore. If the network still isn't working properly in some way, it's almost certainly a misconfiguration of the network's captive portal / firewall / router configuration, not your Mac.

If you think you're still getting redirected, then use any web browser to go to an insecure HTTP web page, and deal with the network's captive portal login from within your browser.

It has to be insecure HTTP, as opposed to secure HTTPS, because HTTPS is too secure to get man-in-the-middle attacked like that (hopefully). Same with VPN. If you have a VPN configured, you need to try to go to an insecure HTTP site that does *not* go through your VPN tunnel.

Comment: great answer spiff. way better than the answer that tiger hobes gave me.

Answer (score 0):

You can typically open a browser and try to open a webpage. Most hot spots will re-direct you to their authentication page. This is a great alternative to waiting for the pop-up. In MacOS you can change the settings under Settings -> Wi-Fi, there is a checkbox to "Ask to join new networks" Additionally you can Turn Wi-Fi Off then back On, Turning Bluetooth off and on can sometimes help (even though they should be un-related).

Comment: yeah I tried quiting the browser opening it again, going to google.com but that doesn't force the modal open sometimes. sometimes it does.